# Minimal amount of parameter types

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, type-parameter

Is there a way in java (currently 8 but I'm also interested in answers for later versions) to go from :

```
public interface HasId<K> {
    K getId();
}

public interface ItemFinder<I extends HasId<K>, K> {
    I findById(K id);
}
```

To something more like

```
public interface HasId<K> {
    K getId();
}

public interface ItemFinder<I extends HasId<K>> {
    I findById(K id);
}
```

All in all : can't `K` be inferred from `I` ?

Deep down I feel it should be possible but I can't seem to figure out a way to do it (leading me to question my gut on that).

Comment: IMHO that is impossible... Maybe try Kotlin?

Comment: No, you've got to do it the first way.

Comment: I understand that the language has no way to make it, now is it fundamentally impossible ? Is there hope that a future java57 may have a parameter-type inference that allows this ?

Comment: In the second snippet, K could be an already declared class or interface. The compiler wouldn't know that you meant K to be a type parameter.

Comment: Isn't it more idiomatic to put K first, so that the human eye parsing the declaration would see K and understand it's a type parameter and then already know what K is when it sees it again in `HasId<K>`?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I get it, I know this syntax isn't correct I was just hoping that someone would come up with something clever like a `public interface <K> ItemFinder<I extends HasId<K>>` or something ...

Comment: No this is not possible, because there would be no way to decide if `K` is supposed to be a type parameter or a concrete type. You have to specify that `K` is a type parameter.